# Ошибка мускула

Tags: php, mysql

Может я что то не так делаю? Через визуальный редактор пытаюсь добавить запись в БД поле text. Вот кусок кода

`

```
if (@$_POST['save'] ){
$text=$_POST['content1'];
$anot=($_POST['anot']);

$pole=$_POST['pole'];
$titul=$_POST['titul'];
if (!$text || !$pole || !$titul) {
echo ("Поле не заполнено");
}
else {
if ( !get_magic_quotes_gpc() ){
$text=stripslashes($text);
$anot=stripslashes($anot);
$pole=stripslashes($pole);
$titul=stripslashes($titul);
}
$kuda=array(); // определяем название таблицы по ИД

$kuda[10]="news";
$kuda[1]="first";
$kuda[6]="stat";
if ($kuda[$id]==1 || $kuda[$id]==6){

//пишем
mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$kuda[$id]} (title, nazv, text) VALUES ('{$titul}','{$pole}','{$text}')") or die (mysql_error());
echo " <script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert (\"Данные внесены\"); </script>";
} 
if ($kuda[10]){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$kuda[10]} (title, nazv, anot, text) VALUES ('{$titul}','{$pole}','{$anot}','{$ text}')") or die (mysql_error());
echo " <script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert (\"Данные внесены\"); </script>";
}

else echo ("нет такого раздела");
}
}
```

`

Работает через раз. Если объем вносимых данных большой но вовсе ругается. 
Пишет
`

```
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ом.
```

Что делать в чем проблема? уже проверил и перепроверил все что только было ((((((

Answer (score 1):

Вот исправленные запросы, но кажется тут еще дело в самой логике.

```
...
$titul = htmlspecialchars($titul);
$pole = htmlspecialchars($pole);
$text = htmlspecialchars($text);
mysql_query('INSERT INTO `' . $kuda[$id] . '`(`title`, `nazv`, `text`) VALUES(\'' . $titul . '\', \'' . $pole . '\', \'' . $text . '\')') or die (mysql_error());
...
$anot = htmlspecialchars($anot);
mysql_query('INSERT INTO `' . $kuda[$id] . '`(`title`, `nazv`, `anot`, `text`) VALUES(\'' . $titul . '\', \'' . $pole . '\', \'' . $anot . '\', \'' . $text . '\')') or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''news' (title, nazv, anot, text) VALUES ('.апа.','.апапап.','.
Вот что пишет (

Comment: text экранируется символами ``?

Comment: После моей манипуляции

mysql_query("INSERT INTO '{$kuda[10]}' (title, nazv, anot, text) VALUES ('.{$titul}.','.{$pole}.',\''.$anot.'\',\''.$text.'\')") or die (mysql_error());

пишет

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''news' (title, nazv, anot, text) VALUES ('.апа.','.апапап.',\''.
ап' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

может быть проблема в этой строчке ? а точнее в переменной **text**

```
('{$titul}','{$pole}','{$anot}','{$ text}')") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: А что сней не так?

Comment: из вашего кусочка кода:

{$ text}

Comment: ну пробел там, между знаком долара и переменной )

Comment: пробела нет. это видимо при копировании косячнулось

Comment: ok.
А вообще, для решения такого рода проблем, принтуйте sql в браузер,
копируйте запрос, и выполняйте его непосредственно в мускуле..

Во время принта посмотрите внимательно, все ли кавычки на месте, и все ли хорошо..

Answer (score 1):

судя по описанию ошибки, которое у вас выдается, вы пытаетесь записать в базу строку содержащую неэкранированные кавычки в следсвие чего и рушится запрос. просто перед записью в базу сделайте:

```
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
```

для всех полей разумеется.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем юзать стрипслешес, воспользуйтесь обычной регуляркой и оставьте в строке только символы и цифры например. А то что у Вас работает через раз, как написали выше - запрос выводите в браузер. Скорее всего что-то не так с запросом.